# How can I count element of xml from a recursive function in PHP?

Tags: php, recursion, simplexml

Here's what i've tried but the numbers is wrong and I don't know why

[image]

It should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and etc..

Here is my PHP code:

```
function GetNavigations(SimpleXMLElement $element, $level = 0, $mrg = 0)
{   
    $value = trim((string) $element); 
    $children = $element->children(); 
    $attributes = $element->attributes();
    //echo '<ul>';  
    if(count($children) == 0 && !empty($value))
    {   
    if($element->getName() == 'GroupName')
        {
            if($attributes['ParentId'] != '')
            {
                //$mrg = $level/2 * 10;
                echo '<li>'.$mrg.'<a class="btngroup" href="load.php?active=menu&group_name_id='.$attributes['GroupNameId'].'">'.$element.'</a></li>';
            }   
        }
    }

    if(count($children))
    {
        foreach($children as $child)
        {
            GetNavigations($child, $level+1, $mrg+1);
        } 
    }
    //echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetNavigations($child, $level+1, $mrg+1)` will pass the same value of `$mrg` to all children of a node, however many children it has, because `$mrg` is not being changed anywhere else inside that loop. Instead of `$mrg+1`, you could pass `++$mrg` - or more readably, add `$mrg++;` as the line before and just pass `$mrg`.

However, you will still have the problem that the function only knows how many direct children have been displayed, not how many descendants - if you call `GetNavigations` with an `$mrg` value of `2`, and it displays 20 nested items, your next value of `$mrg` will be `3`, not `23`! Although they all have the same name, each time you run the function, you have a new `$mrg` variable.

To get around that, you can either:

- Pass `$mrg` in by reference (by changing the function declaration to be `function GetNavigations(SimpleXMLElement $element, $level = 0, &$mrg)` with the added `&`, so that all copies of the function can write to the same variable.
- Pass the new value of `$mrg` out as the `return` value of the function.

I would probably prefer the second approach, as it's a bit clearer to anyone reading the code what's going on:

```
function GetNavigations(SimpleXMLElement $element, $level = 0, $mrg = 0)
{   
    /* [snip] */

    if($element->getName() == 'GroupName')
    {
            // Increment counter, because we're displaying something
            $mrg++;

            /* [snip] */
    }

    /* [snip] */

    if(count($children))
    {
        foreach($children as $child)
        {
            // Recurse, and get incremented value of counter
            $mrg = GetNavigations($child, $level+1, $mrg);
        } 
    }

    /* [snip] */

    // Let caller know where the counter has got to
    return $mrg;
}
```

Comment: sir itried but it is always displaying "1", or maybe my code is wrong here it is "$i = GetNavigations($xml, 0, $i);"